# Finding method arguments (and types) using Scala 2.10 reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I've learned (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10)) to use extractors to obtain Scala metadata.  I've also noticed `Universe.MethodTypeExtractor`:

> An extractor class to create and pattern match with syntax
>   `MethodType(params, respte)` Here, params is a potentially empty list of
>   parameter symbols of the method, and restpe is the result type of the
>   method.

Great! Sounds like what I want!(?)

But how to get a `MethodType`?  (And why is this an extractor for a method "type" (are methods "types"?) as opposed to say, a method "Def" or "Ref"??)

```
scala> typeOf[List[Int]].member(newTermName("head"))
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method head

scala> res2 match { case MethodType(a, b) => println((a, b)) }
scala.MatchError: method head (of class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol) [...]

scala> res2.asType match { case MethodType(a, b) => println((a, b)) }
scala.ScalaReflectionException: method head is not a type [...]

scala> res2.asTerm match { case MethodType(a, b) => println((a, b)) }
scala.MatchError: method head (of class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol) [...]

scala> res2.asMethod match { case MethodType(a, b) => println((a, b)) }
scala.MatchError: method head (of class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$MethodSymbol) [...]
```

Or am I completely "barking up the wrong tree", so to speak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paramss` (this is an RC1 name, in M7 it is named `params`) and `returnType` are methods of MethodSymbol:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[List[Int]].member(newTermName("head"))
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method head

scala> res2.asMethod.paramss
res4: List[List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol]] = List()

scala> res2.asMethod.returnType
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = A
```

To get a type signature of a method, you should call the `typeSignature` method defined on `Symbol`.

Speaking of why methods are types, it's not entirely correct to say so. There are `DefDef` trees, `MethodSymbol` symbols and `MethodType`/`NullaryMethodType` types - each serving its own purposes within the compiler. Quite soon we'll complete the documentation of the reflection API, so hopefully things will get clearer.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry -- probably should have seen that.  Little confused as to when the information is available by a function, and when to use an extractor.  Documentation would *certainly* help a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: in 2.11 named paramLists

Comment: How do I get the string of "Scala type" for a method? So, for `def foo(a:List[Int]) = ???`, I need the string `scala.List[scala.Int]`.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Pasting here. Something like `val y = x.paramss(0)(0);  y.typeSignature`. Thanks for the reflection API BTW. Really needed this for a long time.