# Scala relfection, finding type parameters of subtypes

Tags: scala, reflection, type-parameter

Now From [Finding type parameters via reflection in Scala 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10) , I can see how to get type arguments, however I would like to get them from a subclassed parameter type. For example I have

```
trait ICommand
trait IHandle[T <: ICommand] {
  def handle(t:T):Unit
}

case class MyCommand(i:Int) extends ICommand
trait MyHandler extends IHandle[MyCommand]
```

So I want to find the ICommand parameter of MyHandler.  So far I can get

```
val t = typeOf[MyHandler]
val s = tt.typeSymbol.typeSignature
```

Where s.toString will give IHandle[MyCommand], however I would like to pull out MyCommand as a symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a shorter way, but this works.

```
scala> typeOf[MyHandler].baseType(typeOf[IHandle[_]].typeSymbol) match { case TypeRef(_, _, List(tpe)) => tpe.typeSymbol }
res8: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class MyCommand
```