# Getting type parameter of a weak type in a macro implementation

Tags: scala, macros, type-parameter

In a macro `impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag]`, if I find that `c.weakTypeOf[A] <:< typeOf[Option[Any]]`, how do I get the type parameter of the `Option`? E.g., when `A` is `Option[String]`, I need to find `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10):

```
c.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head
```