# How do I get the *declared* generic parameter of the type of a member found at runtime in Scala via reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

This is related to [Finding type parameters via reflection in Scala 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10) but the solution given there doesn't work for me. What I'm trying to do is iterate over the members of a class, some of which are lists etc, eg val myField: List[String]. I want to be able to get "String" out of there somehow without having to hack the .toString value of the typeSignature field.

I tried

```
typeOf[member.typeSignature].asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args
```

but apparently the scala.runtime.Type implementation returned by typeSignature is different from the one returned by typeOf (as used in the above question) because I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Types$NullaryMethodType cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeRefApi
```

I also tried:

```
val TypeRef(_, _, tpe :: Nil) = member.typeSignature
```

But then I get this exception:

```
scala.MatchError: => scala.Option[String] (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$NullaryMethodType)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I figured out a way to do this:

```
val NullaryMethodType(tpe) = member.typeSignature
val TypeRef(_, _, tpe2 :: Nil) = tpe
```

Then tpe2 will have the correct value. Right now this crashes on non-generic inputs but I can fix that.