# How to get to type parameters of a reflect.runtime.universe.Type in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-reflect

Suppose I get a Type representing List[Int]:

```
> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
> val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with ...

> class X{ def getList():List[Int] = null  }
defined class X

> val method = mirror.
    classSymbol(classOf[X]).
    toType.
    declarations.
    filter{_.isMethod}.
    map{_.asInstanceOf[universe.MethodSymbol]}.
    filter{ m => m.
    name.
    toString()=="getList" }.
    head   
method: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method getList

> val rt = method.returnType
rt: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.List[scala.Int]
```

How to I go from reflect.runtime.universe.Type (that apparently knows about the type parameter scala.Int) to the actual type parameters?

I see that TypeSymbol has a parm

Some experiments..

```
rt.typeSymbol  // reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class List ... Int is erased
rt.typeSymbol.asInstanceOf[TypeSymbol].typeParams // List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(type A)
rt.takesTypeArgs  // false !!
rt.termSymbol  //None
rt.typeSymbol.typeSignature // Much, talk about generics, but no Int
rt.typeSymbol.asInstanceOf[TypeSymbol].typeParams  // List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(type A)
rt.getClass  // Class[_ <: reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$1
rt.asInstanceOf[TypeRef].sym  // List
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Scala 2.11

You need `rt.typeArgs`, which returns a list of types (in your case it contains a single element: Int).

### Scala 2.10

```
val args = returnType match {
  case r: universe.TypeRefApi => r.args
  case _ => List()
}
```

Comment: universe.Type has no method typeArgs -- its a method of TypeSymbol. When I try to get the typeSymbol, the generics are erased.

Comment: In Scala 2.11.4 it certainly has. What version are you running?

Comment: 2.10  .. . . . . . . ..

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow has the answer for 2.10 here: [Finding type parameters via reflection in Scala 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842729/finding-type-parameters-via-reflection-in-scala-2-10?rq=1)

```
rt.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args
```

. . . . . .